# Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python

Tags: python, аудио

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу воспроизвести музыку формата flac. Пробовал pygame, pydub - не вышло.
Посоветуйте библиотеку для работы с flac.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Playing audio file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578238/playing-audio-file-with-python)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578238/playing-audio-file-with-python

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы просто запустить файл на проигрывание из программы, можно попробовать `webbrowser` модуль, который попытается использовать приложение по умолчанию в системе для проигрывания `.flac` файлов:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('example.flac')
```

В более общем случае можно использовать GStreamer, который поддерживает многие форматы и работает на большинстве распространённых систем. Вот минимальный пример, который проигрывает произвольный медиа-файл (аудио, видео), заданный с командной строки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Play a media file using GStreamer."""
import os
import sys
try:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    from urllib.request import pathname2url
except ImportError: # Python 2
    from urlparse import urljoin
    from urllib import pathname2url

from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
Gst.init(None)

def path2url(path):
    return urljoin('file:', pathname2url(os.path.abspath(path)))

media_uri = path2url(sys.argv[1]) # file:// url to play
print(media_uri)
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)
player.set_property('uri', media_uri)
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    GObject.MainLoop().run()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # stop playing on Ctrl-C
    player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Чтобы завершить скрипт, нажми Ctrl-C.

Вот [более полный пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/de5ebbc08805a941a7f7#file-play-media-py), который показывает как слушать сообщения от Gstreamer, чтобы, например, выйти из программы по окончанию проигрывания файла или начать играть файл заново.

Чтобы установить Gstreamer на Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-gi python3-gi \
    gstreamer1.0-tools \
    gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 \
    gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
    gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: Простите, я в питоне новичок. Не могли бы вы написать комментарии к коду?

Comment: @Xmelnoi: для новичков это тяжёлый для понимания код: GObject introspection (C <-> Python bindings), GObject event loop (bus), Gstreamer (pipelines) -- в комментарии тяжело объяснить. И к сожалению, чтобы вносить даже маленькие изменения в код, необходимо пусть частичное, но понимание, что код делает. 

Чтобы предложить более простое решение, нужно более подробно описать в вопросе, что включает в себя "работа с flac".

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести всю информацию о аудиофайле формата flac. То есть все, что храниться в метаданных и воспроизвести файл. Т.к. первая часть задания делается вручную, без подключения специальных модулей работы с flac, а во второй части разрешено пользоваться готовыми модулями.
И с первой частью я вроде более менее справляют, а вот воспроизвести аудио файл никак не могу. И вся работа с flac с помощью готовых модулей сводится к воспроизведению файла.

Comment: @Xmelnoi: Достаточно ли: `python -mwebbrowser example.flac`?

Comment: @Xmelnoi: Что произойдёт, если выполнить эту команду? Что гугл говорит, если ввести `python webbrowser`?

Comment: python webbrowser - модуль включает в себя функции, чтобы открыть URL-адреса в интерактивных приложениях браузера.А python -mwebbrowser example.flac, как я понял из того что говорит гугл, это работа из командной строки 
[смотрел здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331269/error-while-opening-subprocess-python) но программа должна воспроизводить аудио не из командной строки.

Comment: @Xmelnoi: `webbrowser` можно использовать как библиотеку (не из командой строки). [Ссылка из вашего комментария](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13332799/4279) содержит даже пример кода, который показывает как это сделать!

Comment: Спасибо, да я это понял, что  webbrowser модуль, который можно подключать. Но если вы говорите, что с помощью него можно воспроизвести flac, то я попробую. Спасибо огромное за ответ