# Вывести видеопоток с ip-камеры на экран

Tags: python, видео

Ребят, подскажите, что использовать? Задача вывести видеопоток с ip-камеры на экран.
Нашёл несколько графических библиотек - wxWidgets, PyGTK, tkinter.
Какая из них это сможет, или вообще обращаться к  Pygame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это библиотеки графического интерфейса. Для работы с видео используйте OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт питона не уверен, но, как вариант, могу предложить к рассмотрению связку FFMpeg + Qt. Первый для захвата, второй для воспроизведения. Пример простой реализации [по ссылке](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kevaoce8shnea7j/AADzVEU_pxttlO5xXPOQRKxIa?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы показать видео, доступное по заданной ссылке, можно GStreamer использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Play a media file using GStreamer."""
import sys
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst

Gst.init(None)
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)
player.set_property('uri', sys.argv[1]) # file://, http://, etc
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    GObject.MainLoop().run()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # stop playing on Ctrl-C
    player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Пример кода адаптирован [из другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/384902/23044).