# Как воспроизвести аудио поток в python?

Tags: python

Есть аудио [поток](http://ic7.101.ru:8000/c15_3)

Записывать я его научился:

```
import requests
def save_stream():
    stream_url = 'http://ic7.101.ru:8000/c15_3'

    r = requests.get(stream_url, stream=True)

    with open('./stream.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        try:
            for block in r.iter_content(1024):
                f.write(block)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Теперь я хочу научится его воспроизводить?)

Все, я разобрался)
Вот готовый [код](https://gist.github.com/llpoqpeccop/a002d66b5fa406f57c268c4694fc751f), пишет и сразу воспроизводит аудио поток.

Comment: Вопрос неясен: вы хотите (потенциально бесконечный) аудио поток воспроизводить или у вас вопрос как mp3 воспроизвести в Питоне? (тогда не имеет значения откуда mp3-файл на диск попал).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384804/23044) (как webbrowser так и Gstreamer можно попробовать чтобы исходную ссылку воспроизвести или сохранённый файл проиграть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать pyglet:

```
def playFile(sound,reps=1):
    import pyglet
    from pyglet.media import Player

    player = Player()
    song = pyglet.media.load(sound,streaming=False)
    for i in range(reps):
        player.queue(song)

    player.play()
    def callback(dt):            
        pyglet.app.exit()

    pyglet.clock.schedule_once(callback,song.duration*reps)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Не особо изящно, громоздко, но работает.

Comment: Работает) но чтобы воспроизвести .mp3 пришлось подключить avbin.dll
pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
pyglet.have_avbin=True
Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Как вариант можно кинуть в \Windows\System32