# Посоветуйте модуль для Python 3 (проигрывание mp3,wav)

Tags: python, mp3, модули, wav

Мне нужно найти встроенный модуль для проигрывания mp3, wav файлов в Python 3. Что можете посоветовать? Пробовал использовать другие, но пишет, что не может найти модуль.

Comment: А что мешает взять и установить ненайденный модуль?

Comment: Другие это какие? Как правило, если вы не пробуете использовать модуль, упоминание которого вы нашли в интернете, но Python его не находит, то этот модуль нужно установить.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384804/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `mixer` из модуля `pygame`. Документация к mixer расположена [тут](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html). Импортировать только функции `mixer` можно так: `from pygame import mixer`

Также подойдёт **The Snack Sound Toolkit**. Это кроссплатформенное решение, поэтому на мой взгляд более перспективно в плане выбора. Инфу найти можно по этой [ссылке](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/)

Если ОС - Windows, то ещё можно попробовать [winsound](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/winsound.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо, но с winsound к сожалению у меня интерфейс зависает (tkinter). Попробую The Snack Sound Toolkit.