# Чтение WAV в Python

Tags: python, файлы, аудио, wav

Есть WAV файл типа такого: 3 секунды идёт писк, потом тишина секунду, потом опять пищит секунд 5, и так далее. Частота писка известна. Длительность писка и молчания всё время разные. Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить длительность писка/тишины в Python? Что-то сам найти не могу. Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654090/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-python-3-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-mp3-wav?rq=1)

Comment: Тишина полная или есть тихий фоновый шум? Тишина на уровне ноль или есть смещение? От этого может зависеть сложность обработки звука

Comment: Есть модуль [wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html). Нужно прочитать фреймы, там где разница между соседними фреймами меньше определенного предела в течение какого-то времени - это и есть тишина.

Comment: Фонового шума нет. Либо писк либо тишина(что-то типо азбуки Морзе). А как это сделать в wave, в этом и проблема