# Как подменить источник звука с микрофона на mp3 файл?

Tags: python, windows, аудио

Хочу направить аудио поток из воспроизводимого mp3 файла так, чтобы другая программа думала, что звук идёт будто бы с микрофона. Как это организовать?

Например, у меня есть mp3-файл, и с помощью скрипта python он будет воспроизводить его через мой микрофон, чтобы другие в голосовой комнате услышали его. Как я уже сказал, это всего лишь пример.Как можно подать файл на микрофон? Если грубо в windows есть стандартное средство Стерео микшер при включение его он дублирует звук из твоего аудио выхода и на аудио вход, но я не знаю как сделать это программно.

Comment: Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: если возможность реализации

Comment: Он имеет ввиду проигрывание звуков на "другой конец провода"

Comment: Подать какой либо ауди файл на микрофон (аудио вход)

Comment: Микрофонный АЦП (микросхема такая) умеет преобразовывать только аналоговый сигнал в цифровой, но никак не наоборот. То есть даже схемотехника железа на такой изврат не рассчитана.

Comment: Что происходит, если ввести в командной строке `python -m webbrowser ваш.mp3`? Чтобы вы хотели чтобы происходило вместо этого? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384804/23044

Comment: Обычно воспроизведение бывает через динамики, а через микрофон — запись. Вы точно ничего не перепутали?

Comment: Точно не перепутал если грубо в windows есть стандартное средство Стерео микшер при включение его он дублирует звук из твоего аудио выхода и на аудио вход, но я не знаю как сделать это программно.

Comment: `он будет воспроизводить его через мой микрофон, чтобы другие в голосовой комнате услышали его` — вы хотите что-то вроде [этого](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbIiUYf7oYM)? Тогда заголовок вопроса надо откатить к предыдущей версии.

Comment: Погуглите по virtual audio cable, можно будет создать источник звука, в который направить воспроизведение из плеера.

Answer (score 1):

В [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) при использовании [pulseaudio](/questions/tagged/pulseaudio) можно запросто сымитировать будто бы на микрофон поют мелодию, записанную в любом вашем файле. То есть можно обмануть любую программу, и она "услышыт" с микрофона заранее записанную музыку.

Пусть далее `$audiofile` означает ваш файл со звуком, `$tempfile` - какой-то временный файл, `$sinkname` - название стока для пульсы (можно придумать любое), `$program` - имя программы, которую вы хотие обмануть. Тогда командуйте:

```
lame -t --decode $audiofile $tempfile
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=$sinkname
pacat --device $sinkname $tempfile &
PULSE_SOURCE=$sinkname.monitor $program
```

Первой командой мы декодируем mp3 файл в wav файл, без заголовков. Это шаг обязательный из-за того, что сам PulseAudio не может напрямую работать с mp3.
Второй командой созаём новый пустой аудио сток, из которого будет слушать наша программа. В третьей строчке происходит запись раскодированного wav в только что созданный сток (в фоновом режиме, обратите внимание на амперсанд в конце). Ну и на последней строке происходит запуск с подменённой переменной окружения, в которой задаётся источник по умолчанию.

У каждого стока в PulseAudio есть источник, с которого можно прослушать то, что записывается в сток. Имя у него такое же как у источника плюс `.monitor`.

Если программы lame у вас нету, либо поставьте её, либо воспользуйтесь вашим любимым аудиопроигрывателем. Первую строчку проигнорируйте, а третью замените на:

```
PULSE_SINK=$sinkname ваш_проигрыватель $audiofile
```

Проигрыватель запустится и будет играть музыку для нашей `$program`.