# Модуль для воспроизведения музыки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте модуль для воспроизведения музыки в python и покажите пример.

Comment: Пробовал но либо что-то не работает либо ошибка(хотя все написано как на примере)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384804/23044)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/384804/%d0%92%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-flac-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вам пример:

```
import pyglet


sound = pyglet.media.load('mysound.mp3', streaming=False)
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Конфисковано с: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578238/playing-audio-file-with-python

Answer (score 2):

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\music.mp3')
```