# Сохранение и воспроизведение mp3-файла, полученного по HTTP

Tags: python, requests, python-3.6, text-to-speech

Необходимо синтезировать русскую речь на Python 3.6. Решил воспользоваться Yandex SpeechKit. В документации сказано, что в качестве ответа сервер возвращает звуковой файл в заданном в запросе формате (в моем случае mp3). Как дальше можно сохранить или воспроизвести этот файл?

Comment: Это две разные задачи, разделите вопрос на два отдельных. Впрочем, по-моему оба вопроса уже где-то обсуждались на просторах этого сайта

Comment: Хорошо, допустим речь идет только о сохранении полученного файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы воспроизвести аудио, нужно его сначала сохранить.
Это делается очень просто с помощью библиотеки [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) и [pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home)

```
import requests
import pyglet
# ... Ваш код
text_to_speech = ''  # текст, который будет воспроизведён
request = requests.get('https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/tts', params={'text': text_to_speech})
with open('foo.mp3', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(request.content)
song = pyglet.media.load('foo.mp3')
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Без сохранения в файл, к сожалению, сделать немногим сложнее, в pyglet я такой "фичи" не нашёл. Может потому что плохо искал, не знаю
Но для таких целей мне подошёл [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Правда с установкой придётся немного повозиться, т.к. на данный момент очень мало актуальных инструкций в интернете.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы воспроизвести файл на лету, можно в [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) его открыть:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/tts?text=I%27m+sorry+Dave%2C+I%27m+afraid+I+can
... %27t+do+that')
```

Можно и в командной строчке запустить:

```
$ python -mwebbrowser 'https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/tts?text=I%27m+sorry+Dave%2C+I%27m+afraid+I+can%27t+do+that'
```

Можно без браузера, с помощью Gstreamer воспроизвести:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Play a media file using GStreamer."""
import sys
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst
Gst.init(None)


def on_bus_msg(bus, msg):
    if msg is None:
        return
    elif msg.type is Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        sys.exit()
    elif msg.type is Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        print("Got message of type ", msg.type)
        print("Got message of src ", msg.src)
        print("Got message of error ", msg.parse_error())
        player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        sys.exit('error')
    else:
        pass  # ignore other messages


media_uri = sys.argv[1]  # pass url
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)
player.set_property('uri', media_uri)
bus = player.get_bus()
# listen for GStreamer's messages
watch_id = bus.connect("message", on_bus_msg)
bus.add_signal_watch()
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
try:
    GObject.MainLoop().run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:  # stop playing on Ctrl-C
    player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Пример:

```
$ ./play-url 'https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/tts?text=I%27m+sorry+Dave%2C+I%27m+afraid+I+can%27t+do+that'
```

Пример как локальные файлы можно принять и как установить Gstreamer на Ubuntu см. [Воспроизведение музыки формата Flac в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384804/23044).